# use ffmpeg if in time parameter

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I need using If in -t parameter.
If time > 3 secs, speed up to N level and normal.
If time < 3 secs, ffmpeg execute in normal.
I scale video for telegram stickers (-vf scale=w=512:-1), I need speed up for long vids and limit it to 3 seconds.

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: @Cubix48 im not stuck, my code working normal, but i need speed up if video longer than 3 secs

Comment: FFmpeg is not intended to do video analysis in general, so you need to take care of your required condition in Python with ffprobe or other means of probing the video file to detect the duration. Also, what does "speed up to N level" mean?

Comment: @kesh absolutely random speed level

Comment: OK... whatever that means,.. I hope you can resolve your issue via if-else statement in Python